# What IC is ATMLH714?

Tags: identification, eeprom

I am diagnosing a PCB that has an 8 pin IC with marking: ATMLH714. I couldn't find any datasheet for the component online. However, I suspect it is an EEPROM possibly by Atmel.

Would anyone have any idea regarding this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described markings match with an [Atmel AT24C01C/AT24C02C](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Microchip-Tech-AT24C01C-SSHM-T_C36157.pdf) EEPROM.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/EEPROM_Microchip-Tech-AT24C01C-SSHM-T_C36157.html))